# Javascript Fade when in ViewPort

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm learning Javascript and wanting to use the following feature to cause a fade effect with vanilla javascript instead of Jquery. The code no longer runs now that I've altered it. Can someone help me see what I'm doing wrong? For reference I'm using it with codepen.io/staffan-ad/pen/zaLevE

**The Original Jquery:**

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  var pageTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
  var tags = $(".tag");
  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i];
    if ($(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
      $(tag).addClass("visible");
    } else {
      $(tag).removeClass("visible");
    }
  }
});
```

**My version:**

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  const pageTop = document.scrollTop;
  const pageBottom = pageTop + window.height;
  const tags = document.querySelector(".tag");
  for (var i = 0; i <tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i];
    if (tag.position().top < pageBottom) {
      tag.addClass("visible");
    } else {
      tag.removeClass("visible");
    }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  var tags = document.querySelectorAll(".tag");
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i];
    var tagPosition = tag.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (tagPosition.top < windowHeight) {
      tag.classList.add("visible");
    } else {
      tag.classList.remove("visible");
    }
  }
});
```

`document.querySelector` returns a single document object. You shoud use `document.querySelectorAll` when targeting multiple elements, and `.addClass` does not exist in Javascript.

#### References:

http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ - For Jquery to Vanilla JS conversion